# Updating/Calling JTable rendering when a value is changed MANUALLY/DYNAMICALLY

Tags: java, swing, jtable

so i want my JTable to render everytime a value in a variable is changed however this is not taking place, the table is only getting rendered either when I click on it, or move it out of view then back in. Any suggestions? I am using a custom TableCellRender as posted below.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class myRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public myRenderer()
   {
       super.setOpaque(true);
   }

   @Override
   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
           int row, int column) {
       setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
       setText(value.toString());
       Color myColor = new Color(255, 253, 117);
       setBackground(myColor);
       if(value == Integer.valueOf(-1))
       {
           value = null;
           setText("");
           return this;
       } 
       for(int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
           if(value == Integer.valueOf(finalClass.done[i])) //this value changes during the program.
           {
               setBackground(Color.cyan); 
           }
       }
       return this;
   }

}
```

I want my table to render everytime that the value in `finalClass.done` is changed in any other part of the program. any ideas? i tried the revalidate option, but got no results.

EDIT: 
Here is a minimal version of finalClass, which when run together with the above mentioned renderer code, can reproduce the same error I'm facing.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class finalClass {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    static int[] done = new int[90];
    Integer[][] slip = new Integer[9][5];
    String colHeader[] = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
    JTable table;
    finalClass() {
        for(int i = 0; i<90; i++)
            done[i] = -1;
        int cnt = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x<9; x++ ) {
            for(int y = 0; y <5; y++) {
                slip[x][y] = cnt++;
            }
        }
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(slip, colHeader) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
               //all cells false
               return false;
            }
        };
        table = new JTable(slip, colHeader);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new myRenderer());
        table.setModel(tableModel);
        frame.add(table);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new finalClass();
        try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        done[5] = 10; 
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all in advance for bearing with me. I'm new here so it might take a little time for me to understand how things are done around here. sorry to waste your time and thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You need to tell the `TableModel` that something has changed (and in general which cell)

Comment: But is this object in fact part of the table model?

Comment: You could have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753562/adding-progress-bar-to-each-table-cell-for-file-progress-java/13755155#13755155) which demonstrates updating the progress bar of a number of cells

Comment: `value == Integer.valueOf(-1)` << that's playing with fire, use `Object.equals` to compare objects.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter , the value in the array done is not included in the table. it is just a randomly generated by a different part of the code, and I want the changes to reflect.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, im sorry but i didnt quite understand how are you telling the table that something has changed in the example u listed. i believe the file inputs and such have confused me there. could u please dumb it down for me a little. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TT. thank you for ur suggestion. I'll see to implement the same in my code.

Comment: Please make your code [mre]. We should be ablr to copy-paste and run it.

Comment: @c0der, done. my apologies that i did not know how to do that until now. i hope that might be enough to help. as in the code, the cell background of 10 only changes when I click on it, and not on its own.

Comment: Well done. It is certainly more of an MRE now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the value shows only after you move the table or click on it, is that by doing so you force a repaint. 
You can verify it by invoking `frame.repaint()` after `done[5] = 10;`

The following is a one-file MRE (copy paste the entire code into `FinalClass.java` and run):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Arrays;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class FinalClass {

    private final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private final int[] done = new int[90]; //better avoid static
    private final Integer[][] slip = new Integer[9][5];
    private final String colHeader[] = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
    private JTable table;

    FinalClass() {

        Arrays.fill(done, -1);
        int cnt = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x<9; x++ ) {
            for(int y = 0; y <5; y++) {
                slip[x][y] = cnt++;
            }
        }

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(slip, colHeader) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
               //all cells false
               return false;
            }
        };

        table = new JTable(slip, colHeader);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyRenderer());
        table.setModel(tableModel);
        frame.add(table);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void refresh(){
        frame.repaint();
    }

    void done(int index, int value){
        done[index] = value;
        refresh();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FinalClass f = new FinalClass();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            f.done(5, 10);
        } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    //follow java naming conventions
    class MyRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

           private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

           public MyRenderer()
           {
               super.setOpaque(true);
           }

           @Override
           public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                   int row, int column) {
               setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
               setText(value.toString());
               Color myColor = new Color(255, 253, 117);
               setBackground(myColor);
               if((int)value == -1)
               {
                   value = null;
                   setText("");
                   return this;
               }
               for(int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
                   if((int)value == done[i]) //this value changes during the program.
                   {
                       setBackground(Color.cyan);
                   }
               }
               return this;
           }
        }
}
```

---

Side notes: 
1. If you want the table to respond automatically to change in the undelying data, you need to apply the change to its model as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61707812/3992939) to your previous question.

2.Modifying `done` from more than one thread needs to be synchronized. 
3.It is recommended to follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/)